# iOS7 framework for "introduction guide" page

Tags: ios, frameworks

I'm searching for a framework that help me create a "how to use this app" view on ios7.
I need something like that: [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2ZQf.png)

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [MyBlurIntroductionView](https://github.com/MatthewYork/MYBlurIntroductionView).
It's easy to install and easy to use.

Other nice libraries:

- [MyIntroductionView](https://github.com/MatthewYork/iPhone-IntroductionTutorial) (same as MyBlurIntroductionView, without blur options)
- [EAIntroView](https://github.com/ealeksandrov/EAIntroView)
- [GHWalkThrough](https://github.com/GnosisHub/GHWalkThrough)
- [ICETutorial](https://github.com/icepat/ICETutorial)
- [AOTutorial](https://github.com/Appsido/AOTutorial)

Most of them are easy installable via [`CocoaPods`](http://cocoapods.org/)